# Check if any textfield, textview or label changed for a UIViewController..?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a view controller and it contains n number of `UITextFields` and `UItextViews` and `UILabels`, is there anyhow I can get notified if any of them changes..?

I can do it by manually looking at each of them in their respective `TextDidChangeNotification` and similar but I am looking for a more optimized way of doing this, where I don't have to worry about each of them .

Comment: Surely if a label changes you must know about it because your code is changing it? For `UITextField` and `UITextView` just set yourself as there delegate and check the `*DidEndEditing:` delegate method.

Comment: so it seems it comes down to the fact that I will have to check each and every UIComponent... :/

Comment: How do you mean you'll have to check each component? The delegate method will give you the `UIText*` that changed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Assumes you don't use tag values now - if you do small change to create
// and index set, add the ones you use, so all new ones assigned are unique.
// assumes ARC
```

1) New ivar:

```
{
    NSMutableDictionary *savedValues; 
}
```

1) When you want to baseline the values:

```
savedValues = [self snapshot];
```

2) call this to baseline current values initially then at any later point:

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *)snapshot
{
    NSInteger tag = 1;
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:[self.view.subviews count]];

    for(UIView *v in self.view.subviews) {
        if([v isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]] || [v isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]] || [v isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {
            if(v.tag == 0) v.tag = tag++; // will happen once
            // EDIT below
            [dict setObject:[NSString stringWithString:[(id)v text]] forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:tag]];
        }
    }
    return dict;
}
```

4) When you want to see if anything changed:

```
- (BOOL)anyChanges
{
    NSDictionary *currentDict = [self snapshot];
    return [currentDict isEqualToDictionary:savedValues];
}
```

Comment: Excellent... I am impressed.. :)

Comment: Will this also take into account the labels added on the tableview inside my view controller..?

Comment: it crashes at         [dict setObject:[NSString stringWithString:[(id)v text]] forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:tag]];
 saying that [UIView text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance. I guess we are missing something here.

Comment: "[dict setObject:" should have been inside the if statement, its modified above now.

Comment: Yeah got that... had figured that out.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make your class to handle UIControlEventValueChanged event in your textfield, textview or label's value is changed. Add this line ViewDidLoad method:

```
  [youLabel addTarget:self action:@selector(valueChanged:) 
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];  
  // add for textfield, textview also if needed
  [youTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(valueChanged:) 
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
  [youTextView addTarget:self action:@selector(valueChanged:) 
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Now selector would be called when ever value is changed

```
- (void) valueChanged:(id)sender{
  if(sender isKindofClass[UILabel class])
  {
    //label value changed here to differntiate used tag
    if([sender tag] == 0) 
     ....
     ....
  }
  else if(sender isKindofClass[UITextField class])
  {
    // textField value changed to differntiate used tag
    if([sender tag] == 0) 
     ....
     ....
  }
  else if(sender isKindofClass[UITextView class])
  {
    // textview value changed to differntiate used tag
    if([sender tag] == 0) 
     ....
     ....
  }
 }
```

Comment: This is what I thought of doing earlier, but the problem with this approach is I have to register for each and every UIElement, and in case if I have 40 than this would mean 40 registrations.

Comment: add tag to each and every UIElement. i assume u understood to  differntiate UIElements

Comment: I'm guessing you used `0` everywhere by accident?

Comment: UIElement is of differnt types so each different type may have tag 0. u can also consider sequence numbering

Comment: But tag is an `NSInteger` and one can probably assume that it will be initialised to `0` so this would not differentiate anything

Answer (score 0):

You should use one method for all textFields, textView and Labels. and give a unique tag to textFields and textViews and labels. which help you for define it's textField ,textView or Label.

```
if(sender.tag == 1000)//UILabel
{

    UILabel *label=(UILabel *)sender

      //write own code for label what do you want.

}
 else if(sender.tag == 2000)//UITextField
{
    UITextField *textField=(UITextField *)sender

      //write own code for textField what do you want.

}
else if(sender.tag == 3000)// UITextView
{
    UITextView *textView=(UITextView *)sender

      //write own code for textView what do you want.

}
```